# how to add multiple frames in xml

Tags: android, xml

Hi in the below xml using drawable i was added frame.Now,for single one I am displaying personal information In the same way how to display multiple but title should be different.

How do that one any one can help me.

**updated**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:background="@drawable/frame1">
        <RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <!--  This is the main content -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="280dp"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/frame1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="20dp" >

       <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical"
        android:background="#DFECEB"
        android:orientation="vertical" >



        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="First Name:"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/first_name"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded"
                android:cursorVisible="true"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="#000000" >
            </EditText>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Last Name:"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/last_name"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded"
                android:cursorVisible="true"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="#000000" >
            </EditText>


        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Email:"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/email"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded"
                android:cursorVisible="true"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="#000000" >
            </EditText>


        </LinearLayout>
         <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Mobile No."
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/mobile_no"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded"
                android:cursorVisible="true"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="#000000" >
            </EditText>


        </LinearLayout>




    </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>


    <!--  This is the title label -->
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white" android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Personal Information"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp" android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

</RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: use android:layout_weight

Comment: Your question is not clear, you'd get better answers if you update your question with an easier to understand explanation.

Comment: @BunnyRabbit Now,see my updated question and explantion

Comment: Please learn English then post your question.

Answer (score 2):

Am not 100% sure , what you are asking. If my understanding is correct, you want to wrap the frame . If so, try editing your Relative layouts height to Wrapcontent.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp" android:background="@drawable/frame1"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:padding="5dp">
```